# Python XPath include missing elements

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

```
<tree>
    <item>
        <element1>somedata</element1>
        <element2>moredata</element2>
        <element3>data?</element3>
        <optional_element>data!</optional_element>
    </item>
    <item>
        <element1>somedata</element1>
        <element2>moredata</element2>
        <element3>data?</element3>
    </item>
    <item>
        <element1>somedata</element1>
        <element2>moredata</element2>
        <element3>data?</element3>
        <optional_element>data!</optional_element>
    </item>
    <item>
        <element1>somedata</element1>
        <element2>moredata</element2>
        <element3>data?</element3>
    </item>
</tree>
```

I have an XML document like this one, what i am trying to accomplish is to get this kind of output:
`["data!", "", "data!", ""]` instead of just `["data!", "data!"]`
So far i have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12997695/1942773) approach without being able to make it work (the list will still just include elements that are present).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`findtext()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findtext) and specify the `default`:

```
[item.findtext("optional_element", default="") for item in tree.findall("item")]
```

Demo (using `lxml`):

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> 
>>> data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
... <tree>
...     <item>
...         <element1>somedata</element1>
...         <element2>moredata</element2>
...         <element3>data?</element3>
...         <optional_element>data!</optional_element>
...     </item>
...     <item>
...         <element1>somedata</element1>
...         <element2>moredata</element2>
...         <element3>data?</element3>
...     </item>
...     <item>
...         <element1>somedata</element1>
...         <element2>moredata</element2>
...         <element3>data?</element3>
...         <optional_element>data!</optional_element>
...     </item>
...     <item>
...         <element1>somedata</element1>
...         <element2>moredata</element2>
...         <element3>data?</element3>
...     </item>
... </tree>
... """
>>> 
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(data)
>>> print [item.findtext("optional_element", default="") for item in tree.findall("item")]
['data!', '', 'data!', '']
```